# Chrome extension wont inject javascript for Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

My chrome extension wont inject javascript when viewing twitter.

My JSON is this

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.twitter.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["jsfunc.js"]
    }
  ],
```

and my JS is a simple `alert("it works");`

If I change matches to `http://www.google.com/*` it works when I open google.com, I see the alert.

But when I just set matches to `https://www.twitter.com/*` and open twitter, I never see the alert...

Why does it work with google and not twitter?  Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter redirects `https://www.twitter.com/` to `https://twitter.com/`.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Problem resolved. Thank you!